How to model custom attributes for entity in PostgreSQL?
I have a table of entities. All entities have required attributes, one of them is bucket_id, and also user can define custom attributes (attribute_name + value) for entity.
I need the following operations with these entities:

Filter entities in one bucket by any combination of attributes (must be fast, only equality)
Get list of names of custom attributes for all entities in one bucket (must be fast)
All custom attributes and some required can be updated (can be slow)

Required attributes can be table columns. I found two ways to store custom attributes:

store json and use GIN-index for fast filtering
store attribute names in separate table and values with (entity_id, custom_attribute_id) key in many-to-many table, but in this case i need to do join on condition like (attribute_id = ? AND entity_id = entity.id) for any new custom attribute in query as i can see

Which one of these approaches is better or can you suggest the better?

As always with this type of question, it depends.
JSONB might be the easier way, especially if when you're querying the entity you always need all of the custom attributes, it may also be more compact as the JSON, if it gets large will be compressed.
Storing as a separate table gives you some flexibility in the index type you use, e.g. if you only require equality, hash indexes can be used, you could also think about partitioning the tables into smaller chunks for performance.
I generally prefer separate tables and joining as they give more flexibility and you use pure SQL for querying but the JSON field is schemaless so it can be more dynamic without touching the table structure.
